# Draw two lines between two nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two nodes

```
\node (A) {A};
\node [below=of A] (B) {B};
```

I can draw a line between them with

```
\draw (A) -- (B);
```

But I need two lines between them. If I'm using

```
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (B) -- (A);
```

it will draw the two lines on top of each other. Can I make some space between them? I have also tried `(A.west) -- (B.west)` but that's too far to the left. The two lines should be quite close to each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below=of A] (B) {B};
  \draw[transform canvas={xshift=-1.5pt}] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[transform canvas={xshift=1.5pt}] (B) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or the shift can be added to the start and end points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below=of A] (B) {B};
  \foreach \s in {-1.5pt, 1.5pt} {
    \draw ([xshift=\s]A.south) -- ([xshift=\s]B.north);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or a double line can be used, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251562/16967) of Alenanno.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `double` key in the `\draw` options.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {A};
\node [below=of A] (B) {B};

\draw[double] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As Paul Stiverson noted in the comments, you can increase the distance by using `double distance=...`. Here's a short gif showing the various sizes from `1pt` to `10pt`.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it! Note that you can change the spacing between the double lines by using something like: `\draw [double, double distance between line centers=1.2em] (A) -- (B);`

Comment: @PaulStiverson Yes I know that but what I don't know is why the caps are showing very thin lines, do you know how to get rid of that? It's quite ugly. :D

Comment: @Alenanno it is as always an anti-aliasing problem, depending on the viewer. You can check for example [this question](anti-aliasing) and the related answers.

Comment: @Kpym I think the link failed. :P

Comment: @Alenanno sorry, here is [the link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220720/9335).

Comment: @Kpym I see, thanks for the link. Although I'm not sure they apply to this case.

Comment: @Alenanno it is. Double line is equivalent two lines drawn one over the other. Try this `\draw[thick, black] (A) -- (B); \draw[thin, white] (A) -- (B);`. The black line is 'longer' because of anti-aliasing. If you transform your pdf to bitmap using ghostscript (without anti-aliasing), there will be no this very thin line.

Comment: @Kpym So it's not actually there and just an artifact in my viewer?

Comment: @Alenanno yes !

Comment: @Kpym Which one do you use? I have Skim and my AA is enabled. Odd.

Comment: @Alenanno as far as I know AA is enabled in all viewers. Only pdf2bitmap converters like ghostscript, Photoshop and Acrobat export to PNG can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

two others solutions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0){A};
\node[draw,right=5em of A] (B)  {B};
\draw[-latex] (A.10)--(A.10-|B.west);
\draw[-latex] (B.-170)--(B.-170-|A.east);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0){A};
\node[draw,right=5em of A] (B)  {B};
\draw[-latex] (A) to [bend right=10] (B);
\draw[-latex] (B) to [bend right=10] (A);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]